# Angular - no coverage report on Linux

Tags: angular-cli, karma-jasmine

When running tests on an Angular project, the coverage files are generated on MacOS (and Windows) but not on Linux.

The same project with the same setup, only difference is the OS.
The same script is used in both cases, on Mac OS it is ran manually, on Linux it is run in a Jenkins pipeline.
Both uses the same Node and NPM versions (installed as part of the script)

When comparing the debug output, everything looks the same apart from:

- expected differences such as OS and path
- Karma config has "usePolling" set to false on Mac OS, but set to true on Linux
- Some Karma constant values are different

  Mac OS:

```
                            O_CREAT: 512,
                            O_EXCL: 2048,
                            UV_FS_O_FILEMAP: 0,
                            O_NOCTTY: 131072,
                            O_TRUNC: 1024,
                            O_APPEND: 8,
                            O_DIRECTORY: 1048576,
                            O_NOFOLLOW: 256,
                            O_SYNC: 128,
                            O_DSYNC: 4194304,
                            O_SYMLINK: 2097152,
                            O_NONBLOCK: 4
```

```
Linux:
```

```
                            O_CREAT: 64,
                            O_EXCL: 128,
                            UV_FS_O_FILEMAP: 0,
                            O_NOCTTY: 256,
                            O_TRUNC: 512,
                            O_APPEND: 1024,
                            O_DIRECTORY: 65536,
                            O_NOATIME: 262144,
                            O_NOFOLLOW: 131072,
                            O_SYNC: 1052672,
                            O_DSYNC: 4096,
                            O_DIRECT: 16384,
                            O_NONBLOCK: 2048,
```

- Coverage text summary is higher on Linux than Mac OS
- debug log is writing coverage on Mac OS but not on Linux

  Mac OS:

```
Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 666 of 666 SUCCESS (39.047 secs / 36.583 secs)
:DEBUG [launcher]: CAPTURED -> BEING_KILLED
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_KILLED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Mac OS 10.15.7)]: CONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
:DEBUG [karma-server]: Run complete, exiting.
:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_FORCE_KILLED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [proxy]: Destroying proxy agents

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 88.21% ( 3997/4531 )
Branches     : 72.42% ( 2676/3695 )
Functions    : 88.16% ( 834/946 )
Lines        : 88.24% ( 3887/4405 )
================================================================================
:DEBUG [coverage]: Writing coverage to frontend/coverage/my-project
:DEBUG [coverage]: Writing coverage to frontend/coverage/my-project
:DEBUG [launcher]: Process ChromeHeadless exited with code null and signal SIGTERM
:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/gs/ljl9_f3j53xbcbxhvmsb7fhr0000gn/T/karma-94420584
:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_FORCE_KILLED -> FINISHED
:DEBUG [launcher]: FINISHED -> FINISHED
:DEBUG [karma-server]: Received stop event, exiting.
:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: FINISHED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [proxy]: Destroying proxy agents
```

```
Linux:
```

```
Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64): Executed 666 of 666 SUCCESS (36.444 secs / 34.728 secs)
:DEBUG [launcher]: CAPTURED -> BEING_KILLED
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_KILLED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64)]: CONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
:DEBUG [karma-server]: Run complete, exiting.
:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_FORCE_KILLED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [proxy]: Destroying proxy agents

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 88.23% ( 3998/4531 )
Branches     : 72.44% ( 2677/3695 )
Functions    : 88.16% ( 834/946 )
Lines        : 88.26% ( 3888/4405 )
================================================================================
:DEBUG [launcher]: Process ChromeHeadless exited with code null and signal SIGTERM
:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /tmp/karma-6788601
:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_FORCE_KILLED -> FINISHED
:DEBUG [launcher]: FINISHED -> FINISHED
:DEBUG [karma-server]: Received stop event, exiting.
:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
:DEBUG [launcher]: FINISHED -> BEING_FORCE_KILLED
:DEBUG [proxy]: Destroying proxy agents
```

Any ideas what we can look into resolving this?
The coverage lcov.info file is needed for reporting purposes.